# If class doesn't exist, scroll to div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to get jQuery scroll to work properly for the code below.

Basically, when class `k.state-disabled` is not active, I'm showing a button called `#checking`.

Once this button is shown for the first time, I want to scroll to the top of that div called `#step1`.

The first portion works (showing the button `#checking`), but the scroll is not working...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if($(".k-state-disabled").length === 0) {
    $( "#checking" ).show();

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#step1").offset().top
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: looks alright to me....

Comment: just a note - you can shorten your conditional: `if (!$('.class').length)` should work :) from a quick look - it looks like this code should work to me, maybe posting html might help :)

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information in your question, so I just threw together a working example similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#scrollablediv").offset().top})
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z970fgxn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code
check your if Condition it work correctly.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
if($(".k-state-disabled").length === 0) {
    $( "#checking" ).show();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#step1").offset().top
}, 2000);

}
```

});